# JMX monitoring EhCache Server MBeans

Tags: java, tomcat, ehcache, jmx

I have a Tomcat instance where I have deployed the ehcache-server. Now I make rest requests to put/get elements from my standalone Java class. Everything works as expected.

Now I would like to monitor the Cache. I understand ehcache-server provides the mbeans of multiple classes. But I can barely find any information on how to register these mbeans.

When I start the jconsole, I can see the Tomcat instance and connect to it. But I do not see any classes (net.sf.ehache.*) of ehcache-server.

The documentation says I could use function `registerMBeans` to register the mbeans. But how do I call a method in a web application from my standalone Java application?

I am afraid I am completely misunderstanding this. I could use some pointers on how to register the mbeans and do the monitoring.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you are not connecting to the correct port, from the [server](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/modules/cache-server.html#monitoring) manual: "The standalone server automatically exposes the MBeanServer on a port 1 higher than the HTTP listening port."

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I am not using the ehcache standalone server. But I still tried connecting to localhost:8081, but that did not work.

Comment: There are 2 different things here it seems, 1. make ehcache to be properly registered with JMX at the server so they appear on jconsole. 2. Write your own JXM client for your app, in other words, make your app to play the jconsole role somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty simple. Add this below config file in your web project

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class SpringCachePocConfig implements CachingConfigurer {

    net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager newCacheManager;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        //Construct you cache here.

        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.addCache(<Your cache>);

        this.newCacheManager = new net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager(config);
        return newCacheManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public ManagementService managementService() {
        return new ManagementService(ehCacheManager(), mbeanServer(), true, true, true, true);

    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }


    @Bean
    public MBeanServer mbeanServer() {
        MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        return mBeanServer;   
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ManagementService.registerMBeans(ehCacheManager(), mbeanServer(), true, true, true, true);
    }


}
```

The `init()` function will register your MBeans. Dont forget to add `@PostConstruct` annotation above your `init()` method